# Unable to open Visibility Scenario Dashboard App : Configure Process Visibility Dashboard

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform

I am trying to configure Visibility Scenario Dashboard app which comes as a package with SAP BTP Workflow in a Workzone Launchpad (following this [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/03/08/configure-process-visibility-dashboard-integration-with-fiori-launchpad-part-7/)). I am getting below error while trying to open the app from Launchpad.

> App could not be opened either due to an incorrect SAP Fiori launchpad configuration or a missing role assignment.
>
> Failed to resolve navigation target "#pv-showScenarioOverview?sap-ui-app-id-hint=saas_approuter_sap.pv.ovp". This is most likely caused by an incorrect SAP Fiori launchpad content configuration or by a missing role assignment.
>
> [image]

Comment: do you user productive or trial version of SAP BPA? which version of Fiori?